# What is the difference between the "Emulate CPU speed" and "CPU type" menu items/configuration options in DOSBox-X?

Tags: dosbox

DOSBox-X has two different menu options under "CPU":

[image: "Emulate CPU speed"]

[image: "CPU type"]

I've set both, but I'm confused as to why they are separate. What happens if I select "286" as CPU type but 166 MHz Pentium MMX as "Emulate CPU speed", for example? Well, I tried that, and it allowed me to do it. Then I ran a game and it certainly seemed to run like a (slow) 286 and definitely not Pentium MMX speed...

Also, what do they mean by "old" and "prefetch"?

Comment: This is a question about current software, and as such is off-topic for RC.

Answer (score 9):

The “Emulate CPU speed” menu only sets the cycles, *i.e.* how fast the emulation runs. You can change this on the fly.

The “CPU type” menu enables or disables actual CPU features. For example, selecting a 286 will cause software looking for a 386 or later to fail. Changing this can involve rebooting the emulated environment.

The “prefetch” options enable prefetch emulation, which can be important for some pieces of self-modifying code — a common anti-debugger technique was to modify the code immediately following the instruction pointer, relying on the fact that prefetched code isn’t affected.

The “old” variant of the 486 corresponds to pre-`CPUID`, pre-`CMPXCHG` 486s: the opcode for `CMPXCG` changed over the 486’s lifetime; new 486s use the same opcode as Pentiums and later CPUs (0x0F 0xB0). In DOSBox-X, the emulation for old 486s throws an illegal opcode exception for `CMPXCHG`, and doesn’t support `CPUID`.

[The “CPU settings” page in the DOSBox-X wiki](https://dosbox-x.com/wiki/Guide%3ACPU-settings-in-DOSBox%E2%80%90X) gives details of the features which are associated with each CPU type.